# Serving Static files Django 1.11.3

Tags: django

I'm new to programming(Python 3.6, Django 1.11.3), I've been teaching myself over youtube and the product's documentation. Now I'm following a youtube video by Chris Hawkes, titled Django 1.10 Tutorial. I followed every instruction down to the nail, but for some reason, the database still doesn't find the static files.here's the link to the project structure, setting.py and index.html. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/q6yfxqt7k4wy43l/AACBcgMiOsdnCyGEvBK4zd45a?dl=0

May you kindly assist, I'd appreciate any pointers as to what I should be doing. 
Thank you

```
    {%load static%}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    ......

        <title>Green Soil Group</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link  rel="stylesheet" href="{%static' 
         vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}'"  >

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <link href=" {%static ' vendor/font-awesome/css/font-
         awesome.min.css' %}' " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?



        <!-- Plugin CSS -->
        <link href=" {%static ' vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css ' 
         %}' " 
         rel="stylesheet">
```

setting.py

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',



    ROOT_URLCONF = 'book.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
           {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR+'/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                      ],
                    },
                },
            ]

    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    STATICFILES_DIR = [
        BASE_DIR + "/static/",
       ]
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you post some of your code to show us what you have tried?

Comment: can you please show me your setting.py file in text.

Comment: Thanks @ The_Cthulhu_Kid

Comment: i struggled a lot with the code formating function initially, which lead me to post a link to the project files @ ammy. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. Make sure that your project follows the typical Django project structure:

   ```
   > book
    \ - settings.py
      - urls.py
      - wsgi.py
      > yourapp
       \ - models.py
         - views.py
         - tests.py
         - admin.py
         - apps.py
   ```

   I see in your `settings.py` that you don't have any apps installed. Add the following entry to your `settings.py`

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
       'yourapp.apps.YourappConfig'  # <- add this entry
   ]
   ```

   Note that i'm using `yourapp` as the app name, but here use your real app name. If you have not started any app refer first to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#startapp).
2. Place your static content inside `books/yourapp/static/yourapp`. Here you can copy your `vendor` directory. Again, refer to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/) for more info.
3. remove the `STATICFILES_DIR` in your `settings.py`
4. add the following entry to your `settings.py`:

   ```
   STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
       'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
   ]
   ```
5. In your templates, refer to the static content in this way:

   ```
   href="{% static 'yourapp/path/to/the/resource' %}"
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'yourapp/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}'">
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really appreciate it ,made all the difference